# What is the Problem with iteritems() in OrderedDict() in python?

Tags: python, python-2.6

Here is my OrderedDict dictionary:

```
 >>> dic = OrderedDict([('16-17,1,5,BUY,BUY,-6,9', 10), ('19-20,1,1,BUY,BUY,-1,1',1)])
 >>> dic
     OrderedDict([('16-17,1,5,BUY,BUY,-6,9', 10), ('19-20,1,1,BUY,BUY,-1,1', 11)])
 >>> for k,v in dic.iteritems():
 ...     print k
 ...     k1 = k.split(',')
 ...     print k1
 ...     print "value",v
 ...     print k1.append(v)
 ... 
 16-17,1,5,BUY,BUY,-6,9
 ['16-17', '1', '5', 'BUY', 'BUY', '-6', '9']
 value 10
 None
 19-20,1,1,BUY,BUY,-1,1
 ['19-20', '1', '1', 'BUY', 'BUY', '-1', '1']
 value 11
 None
```

Why it is printing "None"?

Comment: printing `.append`, `.extend`, `.sort`, anything that modifies the list that already exists, will always print `None`. Just `print k1[-1]` on the next line instead if you want to print the newly appended item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a problem with `OrderedDict`.

`append` returns `None` but modifies the list in place.  So you could replace the line with

```
k1.append(v)
print k1
```

Answer (score 7):

Because `append` returns nothing.

`print` prints the return value of `k1.append(v)`, but there is no return value from `k1.append(v)`

Comment: specificially, the line `print k1.append(v)` prints the result of `k1.append(v)` and `append` does just what MByD says.

Comment: Actually Here Value and List are available,I am appending value into list then How ?